# nextpage break redesign for wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

How do I change the next page tab in wordpress so instead of it showing Next, Previous ect that it shows simply one bar that says Continue, this then goes to the next page.

I cant find this information anywhere

Comment: Yea I was looking at this last night, it dosnt really tell me what I want, e.g. remove the pages in between or allows me to directly style it into a bar in css :/

Comment: And what about [this one](https://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links)?

Comment: Ah so this one I would simple replace the navigation css in my wordpress with the desired navigation in the css sheet?

Comment: You'll have to be a little more explicit (more details), I'm a bit unclear as to what you're asking.